# The probability of a situation for independent events $A,B$ is $P_A\,P_B+(1-P_A)(1-P_B)$; if $A,B$ are dependent, the probability is less or more?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that we have two events $A$ and $B$, and we know that:

- The event $A$ happens with the probability $0<P_A<1$
- The event $B$ happens with the probability $P_B=\frac 12$

I am interested in finding the probability of a situation (let us name it $P_{tot}$) where either **events** $A,B$ happens together, or **complement** events of $A,B$ happen together. I want to consider this probability for both situations when $A,B$ are **dependent** and **independent**.

> If the events are **independent**, then: $\qquad P_{tot}=P_A\,P_B+(1-P_A)(1-P_B)=\frac 12\qquad(1)$

**My question is**

Knowing this information, are we able to make a general claim that if the events are **dependent**, the value $P_{tot}$ will be **less/greater** than the value $(1)$ where the events were **independent**?

Answer (score 2):

If the events are dependent, you wouldn't really be able to tell.

Consider the events where $A=B$, then with certainty $P_{together}=1$.

But if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events (say, $A$ is roll a 1-3 of a fair dice, and $B$ is roll 4-6), then $P_{together}=P(A\cap B)+P(A^C\cap B^C)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. In general, if $A,B $ are dependent and $A\neq B$, then, is it sufficient to add your $P_{togetehr}$ to the formula $(1)$ with negative sign? Can't we say something in general for the case $A\neq B$? @Jellyfish

Comment: @MsMath $P_{together}$ is your $P_{tot}$ in $(1)$, I just thought together sounded better

Comment: @MsMath The case $A=B$ is merely an extreme end of the spectrum of possibilities. You have four possibilities: $A\cap B,$ $A^C\cap B,$ $A\cap B^C,$ and $A^C\cap B^C,$ and you can distribute the probability among them with the only constraint that all individual probabilities have to be between $0$ and $1$ inclusive and the sum must be $1.$ Distribute $0.99$ probability into the buckets $A\cap B$ and $A^C\cap B^C$ and the remaining $0.01$ probability in the other two buckets; what's $P_{tot}$ now? Suppose instead you put only $0.01$ total in $A\cap B$ and $A^C\cap B^C,$ what then?